# How to make the design using widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

If we click on the "Is there an Bitcode Method iOS App?" then the answer should be shown. So I have tried using card in flutter but it's not working. So you can tell me this how to make it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os8Re.png)

Comment: Try Using linear gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help. If you have any requirements or confusion, please consider commenting.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showAnswer = false;
  String answer =
      "At this point, there is no Mobile app on ios or Android. It is available on the trading website and can be accessed via the web on a mobile or laptop.";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  showAnswer = true;
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    transform: GradientRotation(1.2),
                    colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.blueAccent],
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Is there an Bitcode Method iOS App?',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            (showAnswer)
                ? Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          answer,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            height: 1.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: End Result]

Comment: Please consider upvoting or select as answer if it has helped you. It motivates us to help others too.